# Как удалить cookie в PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, cookie

Помогите , пожалуйста, сделать тоже самое:

```
$.removeCookie('lk', { path: '/' });
```

и

```
$.cookie('lk', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
location.replace("/my-works/"); 
e.preventDefault();
```

только в PHP . ВАЖНО: Сделать эту манипуляцию нужно до загрузки контента страницы.

Comment: [Задавалось не раз на ру-со](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8) + подробно освещено в документации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

До формирования шаблона просто выполните.

```
unset($_COOKIE['lk']);
setcookie('lk', null, -1, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

> Чтобы удалить cookie достаточно в качестве срока действия указать какое-либо время в прошлом.

Comment: Я пробовал Ваш вариант вот так - Setcookie('1k', "" ,time()-1000); Это не помогло. Еще важно удалить её до загрузок любых заголовков. я в этом плохо разбираюсь , но у меня шаблон подгружается всё время не тот что нужен

Comment: @AndreiSukharev без кастлей не как... браузер делает запрос в ответ получает куки. можно через кастыль перезагрузить страницу дважды первый раз отправив запрос а второй раз загрузить уже с новыми кукисами.